# Prove that if $x^2 +\bar ax +\bar 1$ has a double root, then $(\mathbb Z/5)[x]/I$ $\cong$ $(\mathbb Z/5)[x]/(x^2)$ where I = $x^2 +\bar ax +\bar 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I'm pretty sure that I am meant to use the evaluation map, but I'm confused about how to write a homomorphism that doesn't have a kernel of $(x-c)$ where $(x-c)^2$ is $x^2 +\bar ax +\bar 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider $(\mathbb Z/5)[x]/(x^2) \to (\mathbb Z/5)[x]/I$ induced by $x \bmod x^2 \mapsto x-c \bmod I$.